# ODBC/OPENQUERY Failing to convert specialcharacters/ASCII correctly and erroring

Tags: sql, odbc, informix

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2019 15.0.2104.1 to query an IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC5XT database via ODBC/OPENQUERY.

I have an issue when any field contains special characters ODBC Interprets the character encoding incorrectly and fails to convert it to a valid character or character set and crashes/errors. The errors can be different, the latest one was failing to interpret '(•ˋ _ ˊ•)' as special characters and instead try to convert it to a datetime2 object

Other errors vary and they are sporadic.

My issue is I need to query this table constantly for a few things (a few times a minute) and the table contains a lot of fields which are free text editable and special characters are a constant issue (don't ask me why).

I attempted to rectify this a while ago and went down a rabbit hole of region encoding between ODBC and Informix and attempting to match them but had no luck.

Has anyone else encountered this, and if so, were you able to resolve it ?

Comment: Character encoding is done base on the GLS (Global Language Support) server and client settings (like DB_LOCALE or CLIENT_LOCALE). What version of the Informix ODBC driver are you using? It shouldn't matter too much (if your are in something older than 3.80).
 
If you have the locales set correctly (based on what your application needs to store, not just the defaults values) there should be no issues converting special characters between codesets (if they are allowed in the code page)

Comment: Identifiers and such are not part of the database locale encoding, but of the odbc encoding itself. Find your `odbc.ini` (e.g. using `odbcinst -j`) and try adding `UNICODE=UCS-2` under the (possibly newly created) `[ODBC]` section. That should convince the odbc driver that it itself needs wide-character encoding.

Comment: @user2722968 that worked perfect. You dont know how long we have been dealing with this issue and doing bandaid work arounds. You are a life saver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comment by @user2722968 fixed my problem for me, if anyone else is experiencing the same issue

> Identifiers and such are not part of the database locale encoding, but of the odbc encoding itself. Find your odbc.ini (e.g. using odbcinst -j) and try adding UNICODE=UCS-2 under the (possibly newly created) [ODBC] section. That should convince the odbc driver that it itself needs wide-character encoding.

Comment: what needs to be explained ?